# error Undefined index en php

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

en php, me sale este error

> Notice: Undefined index: user in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplologin\consultarusuario.php on line 4

### primer php

```
<!--   consultarUsuario.php-->

<?php
include('functions.php'); 
$user=$_GET['user'];                       /* linea 4*/
if ($resultset = getSQLResultSet("SELECT contra FROM `usuarios` WHERE usuario='$user'")) {

        while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        echo json_encode($row);


        }

   }

?>
```

### segundo php ##

```
<!-- functions.php -->
<?php 
header( 'Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8' );


function ejecutarSQLCommand($commando){

  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ejemplologin");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
echo li;
    exit();
}

if ( $mysqli->multi_query($commando)) {
     if ($resultset = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        while ($row = $resultset->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)) {
echo listo;

        }
        $resultset->free();
     }


}



$mysqli->close();
}

function getSQLResultSet($commando){


  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ejemplologin");

/* check connection */
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}

if ( $mysqli->multi_query($commando)) {
    return $mysqli->store_result();




}



$mysqli->close();
}


?>
```

Comment: No estás posteando el valor `user` cuando llamas tu archivo PHP. Debes compartir  la fuente donde se recogen los datos que son enviados al servidor (formulario HTML, URL, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema radica en que la variable no esta definida.
La cual se soluciona de la siguiente manera.

`$user = isset($_GET['user']) ? $_GET['user'] : '';`

Una vez hecho esto, el problema lo tendrás en la consulta, por que al parecer la variable por GET nunca se la envias a la pagina.

La cual debería tener este formato `consultarUsuario.php?user=juan` o mediante ajax con el verbo GET

Saludos

Comment: eso es un comentario o una respuesta???

Comment: es una respuesta rápida.

Comment: Eso sería una respuesta parcial, ya que el problema evidente es la fuente de datos, desde la cual no se está posteando `user`. Efectivamente, pudiste haberlo dicho en un comentario.

Comment: y como posteo user?

Comment: En estricto rigor, el problema seguiria si es que el parametro fuera enviado, ya que ninguna se define la variable $user. No comprendo la molestia.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2882#2882)

Comment: como hago para que me salga,  quiero que  atraves de la url   http://localhost/ejemplologin/consultarusuario.php?user=juan    que me salga los datos de juan

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta para los puristas. La cual responde a la pregunta inicial

Comment: muchas gracias jolsalazar ya me funcionó

Comment: de nada, si gustas puedes votar =)

Comment: no se votar,soy nuevo en esto

Comment: cualqier cosa, no dudes en preguntar, saludos

Comment: Yo creo que si en general el comentario a las preguntas incompletas es **qué es lo que no te funciona?** una respuesta correcta no implica rediseñarle el layout de la aplicación por completo al OP, sino explicarle el origen del error en particular.